# Customize chapterstyle in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I like the `ell` chapterstyle which is built into `memoir`, but I want to customize it.  I like the chapter number and the lines around it, but I want the chapter title to be written in the same size and font as it would be in the `default` chapterstyle.

How can I make this change to the built-in `ell` chapterstyle?  (Hopefully this will also be illustrative in learning how to customize any of the built-in `memoir` chapterstyles.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{ell}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
I want ``Introduction'' to have the same size and font
as it would in the ``default'' chapterstyle.
\end{document}
```

Comment: just copy the code from `memoir.cls` and take it from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As **daleif** suggested in his comment, all you have to do is to look at the code in `memoir.cls`; here's how the `ell` style is defined:

```
\makechapterstyle{ell}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
    \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
    \hrulefill
    \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
    \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
    \hfill
    \raisebox{10mm}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
                              \hspace*{1em}
    \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-3.0\onelineskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \vskip\onelineskip
    \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak}}
```

In your case, the relevant lines are

```
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
```

which set the format for the number and title font. In the default style the number font is boldfaced and uses `\huge` and the title font is set to be boldfaced and `\Huge` and both use roman family, so you can define your own style making the appropriate changes. In the example below I changed both the number and title format to use roman family but, of course, you can change only the title format (I just thought that it is more coherent to maintain the same family for both the number and the title):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{myell}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
    \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
    \hrulefill
    \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
    \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
    \hfill
    \raisebox{10mm}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
                              \hspace*{1em}
    \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-3.0\onelineskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \vskip\onelineskip
    \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak}}

\chapterstyle{myell}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
I want ``Introduction'' to have the same size and font
as it would in the ``default'' chapterstyle.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, for minor changes, you don't have to define your own style; you can simply redefine the appropriate commands after selecting the style. The same result as above can be obtained with:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{ell}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
I want ``Introduction'' to have the same size and font
as it would in the ``default'' chapterstyle.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried Gonzalo's code, but for some reason I cannot use the code and include ` \numtoName{\c@chapter}` as part of any chapterstyle. Is there a particular reason why this is failing? Specially because I know that that particular code works (Using Dalief's suggestion, copied "brotherton" and tried you code, but it does not work). Any help?

Comment: Do you mind posting a full example?

Comment: @daleif I figure out yesterday night a way to make it work, but I my question still stands. I will simplify Gonzalo's code as an example.

   \documentclass{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{mytest}{%
    \chapterstyle{mytest}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    I want ``Introduction'' to have the same size and font
    as it would in the ``default'' chapterstyle.
    \end{document}

Comment: Adding those two `\renewcommand` lines in the example, then the sizes are the same, so I don't see the problem