# ToC Chapter alignment conflict with titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, titlesec

I need all the numbering aligned left, sections and subsections slightly (0 or 2pt maybe?) on the right of chapter. Chapter and section all caps.

The screenshot will explain better what I need:

[image: ToC with no ident]

And this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{abntex2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = {true}, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = {black}, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = {black}, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = {black} %Colour of citations
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\MakeUppercase{\thechapter}}{15pt}{} 
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\thesection}}{15pt}{} 


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introdução}
\section{Objetivos}
\subsection{Objetivos gerais}
\subsection{Objetivos específicos}

\chapter{Exposição do tema}
\section{Tema Geral}
\subsection{Tema específico}

\end{document}
```

As you can see below, when I add `\titleformat` for chapter, it gets an extra space (in red). Whats weird for me is that section has a titleformat but doesn't get buged.

Uppercase is not working for section, but bold is. [`abntex2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/abntex2) class is based on `memoir`, but using memoir returns me chapters without dots and breaks other necessary things on my thesis.

What I get:

[image: ToC with chapter misaligned]

I did try `etoc` and other packages, but it seems to me that I did something wrong that can be fixed without another package.

Or maybe there is indeed a conflict?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by cfr, I look at `abntex2` manual for the upper case command, and it states *doesn't affect ToC*.

I also tried the `sumario=tradicional` option which should use `memoir` default ToC style, but I still get chapters with that weird space:

[image]

If I try to set

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand*\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

I get a undefined control error. It seems like titlesec is indeed inferring with ToC.

> line 4: Undefined control sequence. ...ntrodu\IeC {\c c}\IeC{\~a}o}{3}{chapter.1}
>
> line 8: Undefined control sequence. ...eC {\c c}\IeC{\~a}o do tema}{5}{chapter.2}

Those lines contains:
`\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Introdu\IeC {\c c}\IeC {\~a}o}{3}{chapter.1}`

`\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Exposi\IeC {\c c}\IeC {\~a}o do tema}{5}{chapter.2}`

Comment: You have a choice. Either you can stick with the class you are using and work with its method of configuring things, amending anything which doesn't work out-of-the-box. Or you can use a more standard class and its configuration options, loading any additional packages you need. Packages such as `titlesec` cannot be expected to work with *arbitrary* classes. The class you are using handles things in a certain way. Assuming that you can read the documentation, have a look to see how it tells you to do these things. (I can't read Portuguese so I'm just going by the code.)

Comment: It has options for upper-casing headings, for example. I wouldn't probably recommend the class. I never trust classes and packages which include `\makeatletter... \makeatother`. But perhaps that's just me.

Comment: Sadly my university requires me to follow this standards, which abntex2 seem to implement at some extend. I will have a look at the uppercase part. Thanks.

Comment: There's code for the ToC as well. But it will be easier to figure out for you reading the documentation than trying to do it from the code, which is the only bit I can read. If you get stuck, I can ping people in the chat room. At least one (probably more) will be able to read the docs.

Comment: I did, nothing specific about alignment, just font, levels, numbering etc. It points to memoir manual for further customization.

Comment: Oh, well. Memoir's documentation is very good, though. So if it is just using default stuff from there from the ToC, you should find the information you need to customise it. But it could be that the spacing is in the label if the numbers are being set right for some reason. So still worth looking at the level/numbering stuff.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with titlesec, as I tried a code without the package and got same error. From here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234551/75648

Comment: It helps if you paste the exact error message into your question rather than just saying e.g. that something is undefined. The error message says *what* and, if you're lucky, *where*.

Comment: It is caused by the custom format you are applying to chapters with `titlesec`. Simply loading `titlesec` is fine. But `\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\MakeUppercase{\thechapter}}{15pt}{}` is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30662/discussion-between-g-bay-and-cfr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that something is writing a redefinition of `\cftchapindent` to the very long `\cftlastnumwidth` at the start of the TOC. This happens even without using `\titleformat`, but absent use of `titleformat` another redefinition of `cftchapindent` back to reasonable lengths follows the first. I have looked and looked and cannot begin to guess where either of these lines are coming from, but in any case you can set the lengths right again by putting in yet a third redefinition which puts `cftchapterindent` back as it should be, like so:

```
\tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength  {\cftchapterindent }{0em} \setlength  {\cftchapternumwidth }{\cftlastnumwidth }}
```

Comment: Your solution is better, more efficient since it uses only one line vs. 3 of mine, and it does fix the extra-space. Many Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I still couldn't make `titlesec` work without having this extra space issue.
However after further reading and searching (mostly encouraged by cfr) on `memoir` manual and [`Memoir Chapter Styles`](http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf) I found a way to workaround and display results as I need it. Of course, for section style I still use `titlesec`.

After looking at [this answer by Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50149/75648), I realize it could be all done really simply by creating my own memoir chapter style. My code, as it might be useful to someone is the following:

```
\newcommand*\varhrulefill[1][0.4pt]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern0pt}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\LARGE\bfseries}

\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip 1em \varhrulefill[0.35cm]\vskip\afterchapskip}
```

The vhrulefill is, again [from Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17130/75648).

If I was to define the style at the preamble, then my lists and even ToC title would have the rule, which is not what I wanted.

[image: ToC with chapter style]

If I define the style with `\makechapterstyle` and then "load" it only after ToC, it seems to work, but then again I get the same odd extra spacing at chapters ToC. Don't know why.

To solve this I simply pasted the above code in the preamble of my textual file, witch goes after ToC. I have no idea how this would be done in a single-file document, any suggestions please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the TOC to look like your image (which is weird, but anyway), you should stick with what the class already provides you:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{abntex2}
%\setboolean{ABNTEXupperchapter}{false}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[brazil]{babel} &don't need this, already default
%\selectlanguage{brazil} &don't need this, already default
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = {true}, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = {black}, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = {black}, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = {black} %Colour of citations
}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfont}{\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont\bfseries} %Bera Sans? Really?
%\newcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\Large}}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\normalfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introdução}
\section{Objetivos}
\subsection{Objetivos gerais}
\subsection{Objetivos específicos}

\chapter{Exposição do tema}
\section{Tema Geral}
\subsection{Tema específico}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know why you use Bera Sans for all sectional entries below chapter.

*If you had read the documentation*, you'd have noticed section 6.1: `\ABNTEXchapterfont`, and `\ABNTEXchapterfontsize`, which you can change.

Other macros like `\cftchapterfont` com from `memoir`. (See chapter 9.)

I agree with cfr -- if you want something in all caps, you'd better write it in all caps.